# Edit an specific database registry based on an input

Tags: python, django, crud

I already have some code fully working for this purpose, but i would want to go further.

My actual code list the entire database registrys and let's me edit them, but to go to the one i desire i have to go over the huge list it displays, this is my code:

```
def computer_update_view(request, pk, template_name='computer/computer_form.html'):
    serial = get_object_or_404(Computer, pk=pk)
    form = ComputerForm(request.POST or None, instance=serial)

    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('computer:pc_list')
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"><a href="{% url 'computer:pc_list' %}">Network Admin</a></h2>

<ul>
    <p> <button type="button"><a href="{% url 'computer:computer_new' %}">Add New</a></button></p>
    {% for serie in object %}
        <li>{{ serie.serial }}. {{ serie.name }} - ({{ serie.user_name }})
             <a href="{% url 'computer:computer_edit' serie.serial %}">edit / </a>
       </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>



{% endblock %}
```

So what i want to do is let the user input fox example: User inputs serial "212125" (note that serial is the pk field in the database) and then only that registry shows up to be edited.

How could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

In forms.py edit which fields show up in the form. This can be done with class Meta

```
class Meta:
    model = #model name
    fields = ["""field names go here that will be displayed"""]
```